# Puzzling Batch String Slicing Error

Tags: string, batch-file, slice

So I am creating a program that separates numbers and letters into 2 different variables so it turns "word1234" into a variable containing "word" and a variable containing "1234", what I did was make a program that runs through a variable "info" letter by letter. "Is it a number?" "No", "Is It a letter?" "Yes". When the variable "toggle" was still on the value 0, it would carry on appending the letters to the "weatherd" variable and else append it to the "temperat" variable.
Note: I know my variable and label names are bad, I come up with them in about half a second :)
So it checks if it is a number, if it is the "toggle" variable changes to a 1 and it starts putting the rest of the text into a new variable ("temperat"). I was wondering, once it hits the numbers it gives me an error and crashes, why? Or is there a simpler way than what I'm doing?
Sorry for the massive post, I added some pauses and stuff for debugging, code here:

```
REM PREPARE FOR A MASSIVE AMOUNT OF CODE, all this stuff just gets the current weather, ignore it
@echo off

set "wherestay=%cd%"

cd /d C:
cd\
cd "C:/Users/%USERNAME%/Downloads"
del weather.txt

start chrome.exe teamhaxor.netau.net/getWeather.php

set times=0

:loading
set /a times=%times% + 1
if %times% == 2000 goto failed
if not exist weather.txt goto loading

cd /d C:
cd\
cd "C:/Users/%USERNAME%/Downloads"

< weather.txt (
set /p info=
)

REM PROBLEM STARTS HERE

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

@echo on

set tempery=0

set "weatherd="
set "temperat="

set toggle=0

:loopy

set "char=!info:~%tempery%, 1!"

if "%char%" EQU "0" set toggle=1
if "%char%" EQU "1" set toggle=1
if "%char%" EQU "2" set toggle=1
if "%char%" EQU "3" set toggle=1
if "%char%" EQU "4" set toggle=1
if "%char%" EQU "5" set toggle=1
if "%char%" EQU "6" set toggle=1
if "%char%" EQU "7" set toggle=1
if "%char%" EQU "8" set toggle=1
if "%char%" EQU "9" set toggle=1

pause

if %toggle% EQU 0 (set weatherd=%weatherd%%char%) ELSE (set temperat=%temperat%%char%)

pause

set /a tempery=%tempery% + 1

pause

if %tempery% EQU 15 (goto out) ELSE (goto loopy)

:out

echo %weatherd%
echo %temperat%

setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

REM PROBLEM STOPS HERE

goto afterafterlol
:failed
set weatherd=Failed
set temperat=Failed
:afterafterlol

cd /d C:
cd\

cd %wherestay%

echo %weatherd%
echo %temperat%

pause >Nul
```

Comment: Please include code, don't link to it as that potentially removes the data for future readers. Please explain what you mean by `crash`. Using your suggested `word1234` your code works happily. Sure, there are problems - but no crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question directly, there's an easier way to split your value so that you end up with alpha in one variable and numeric in another.

1. Treat numbers as delimiters, thereby removing them without having to know specifically which numbers will occur.  This will leave you with only the alphabetic portion of the value.
2. Remove the alphabetic portion from the whole, leaving you with the numeric porition.

```js
@echo off & setlocal

set "var=Thunderstorms87"

for /f "delims=0123456789" %%I in ("%var%") do set "condition=%%~I"
call set "temperature=%%var:%condition%=%%"

echo %condition%
echo %temperature%
```

---

In a broader sense, your project seems like a very cumbersome way to scrape not a lot of useful data.  It would be better to query a weather service that offers an API with a structured response that doesn't require splitting strings or other flat text hacks.

Here's an example script that uses [Weather Underground's API](https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/), retrieving and parsing its JSON response.  You'll need to create an account and sign up for a free API key, but you get so much more data and it's so much easier to parse.  And there's no need to spawn a Chrome window to fetch your data this way.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal

rem // weather.bat
rem // https://stackoverflow.com/a/44015647/1683264

rem // go to https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/ for an API key
set "APIkey=pasteyourAPIkeyhere"

if "%~1"=="" (  set "location=autoip" ) else set "location=%~1"

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%APIkey%" "%location%"

rem // end main runtime
goto :EOF

@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

var x = WSH.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"),
    htmlfile = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile'),
    APIkey = WSH.Arguments(0),
    loc = WSH.Arguments(1),
    URL = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/' + APIkey + '/conditions/q/' + loc + '.json',
    JSON = obj = {}, pad = ' ';

htmlfile.write('<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />');
htmlfile.close(JSON = htmlfile.parentWindow.JSON);

x.open("GET", URL, true);
x.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
x.send('');
while (x.readyState!=4) {WSH.Sleep(50)};

response = JSON.parse(x.responseText).current_observation;
obj = {
    "station": response.observation_location.full,
    "timestamp": response.observation_time,
    "conditions": response.weather,
    "temperature": response.temperature_string,
    "humidity": response.relative_humidity,
    "wind": response.wind_string,
    "heat index": response.heat_index_string,
    "wind chill": response.windchill_string,
    "forecast URL": response.forecast_url
};

for (var i in obj) while (i.length > pad.length) pad += ' '
for (var i in obj) {
        var key = (i + pad).substring(0, pad.length);
        WSH.Echo(key + ' : ' + obj[i]);
}
```

Output looks something like this:

[image: weather.bat]

You can use something like:

```js
WSH.Echo(x.responseText);
```

... to view the raw JSON and see all the other data included in the feed.  You can also modify the URL and replace `conditions` with `forecast`, `hourly`, and a [bunch of other options](https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs) (as well as replacing `current_observation` and the `response` object properties as appropriate).

Comment: Wow, this is really neat. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but how can I store the output in batch file variables?

Comment: @CUZLOCKED If you want to delete a comment, hover over the comment and a little "x" should appear at the end of it.  You can also edit comments for the first 5 minutes of their being posted.  Thanks for accepting my answer!  :)

Comment: One slight problem. I tweaked this program a little bit to only give the values (EG: No "Whatever : "), but now when I do this "weather> weather.txt" to put the results into a file, it breaks out of the batch program, why?

Comment: @CUZLOCKED Did you add an API key to the script?  Without an API key some of the JSON objects won't be found and the JScript will throw an error.

Comment: Yes, I added the key but it still breaks out of the script. EDIT: Code here: https://pastebin.com/2gv8b1wp

Comment: @CUZLOCKED I copypasted your pastebin paste into a .bat script and it worked perfectly on this end.  Maybe I need a little explanation about what "breaks out of the script" means.  Do you get an error message?  How is that message worded?  Or are you double-clicking the .bat file icon, expecting the window to stick around when it completes and disappears?  (You should go ahead and delete that paste or regen your API key.)

Comment: I mean, when I call the bat script from another batch file it breaks out of the current program and sits on an open cmd.

Comment: @CUZLOCKED Nope, that tests successfully for me as well.  You're using syntax in your bat script similar to `call weather "location here"`?  Might not be a bad idea to post a new question with your caller script and ask why calling this weather script causes your outer script to exit prematurely.